# Redirect image direct link to attachment page

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect `anyfilename.jpg` to `anyfilename.html`.
I want to redirect every single direct link of images to an HTML (actually a PHP) page. As the example below

```
http://www.example.com/data/out/103/IMG_1081530.jpg
```

When you try to open this image, redirect to an HTML page.

I have done this but it is not working correctly.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^localhost/test$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png) dirimg/$1 [R=301,NC]

RewriteRule ^dirimg/(.*) loadimage.php?image=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: You lose the file extension. Try this maybe? `RewriteRule ^images/(.*)\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png) dirimg/$1.$2 [R=301,NC]`

Comment: Hello, i don't want the extension, the original link that i have is "localhost/test/images/1.jpg" and it redirect rightly to "dirimg/1", then that open "loadimage.php?image=1" and that script localize that file. That's not the problem, the problem that I have is that i don't know how redirect to "dirimg/1" and in that page show an html page, instead, i have a php page that open the same image...

Comment: I'm still not sure I get your problem.. How about replacing `loadimage.php?image=$1` with `html_file.html?image=$1` or `image_$1.html` as an example?

Comment: I have a rule that redirects the links of any image to its same name with the suffix ".html". See "dirimg / image1.html" for example. "dirimage" has its own rule that says "image1" as the parameter for the file "loadimage.php" to serve as a page that will display the image, along with other html content. This image will end up being for example "image1.jpg", but, as it reapplies the htaccess rules, "image1.jpg" does not display anything, since the htaccess redirects it to "image1.html". I explain?

Comment: You did not make clear, that `loadimage.php` is gonna access `images/...`. If that is the case though, this logic does not work. You would have to create another directory for the actual images, like `image_files/...`.